# Generalize definition of open set in higher level of Borel hierachy

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

This question is asked at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267288/definition-of-f-sigma-sets-in-terms-of-varepsilon), but does not receive attention well.

Let $X$ be a metric space.

In Borel hierarchy, $\Sigma_{1}^0$ is the set of all open sets in $X$ while $\Pi_{1}^0$ is the set of all closed sets in $X.$ Then at next level, one has $\Sigma_{2}^0 = \{ \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n : A_n \in \Pi_1^0 \}$, that is, elements of $\Sigma_2^0$ are $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

In $\Sigma_1^0$, its elements can be described in the following manner:

$$O \in \Sigma_1^0 \Longleftrightarrow \forall x \in O, \exists \varepsilon>0, V_{\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq O$$ where $V_{\varepsilon}(x)$ denotes the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$. This definition is very useful as it allows us to visualize open set.

> Question: Does there exist a definition of $F_{\sigma}$ set such that it is in terms of $\varepsilon?$

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Why would there be?

Comment: I think a countable union of closed sets is visual enough. Why would you want something nasty and complicated?

Comment: Just curious. Because in borel hierachy, one has visual definition for first level, which is open and closed. So I wonder whether one can obtain the same for other level.